# Compute Normal Working Hours & Overtime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:-

TableA (National Holidays)

[image]

TableB (Timesheet)

[image]

I wish to compute the normal working hours & overtime for each employee with certain conditions using SQL Server. The expected output should be like this:-

[image]

The conditions are as follows:-

*For Day Shift*

Monday – Friday : up to 8 hr is considered normal. Above 8 hr is considered OT15.
Saturday : up to 4 hr is considered normal. Above 4 hr is considered OT15.
Sunday & Public Holiday : is considered OT20

Division FEP : Official start time is 7:30 AM

Division SER : Office start time is 8:00 AM

(For computation purposes, the start time is based on the division official start time even if the employee arrives much earlier)

*For Night Shift*

Monday – Friday : up to 8 hr is considered normal. Above 8 hr is considered OT15.
Saturday : up to 4 hr is considered normal. Above 4 hr is considered OT15.
Sunday & Public Holiday : is considered OT20

Division FEP : Official start time is 7:30 PM

Division SER : Office start time is 8:00 PM

In addition to that, all National Holidays will be treated as 8 hours normal working for those who are not working & for those who are working, it will be treated as OT20.

Thanks.

Comment: Your text has Division `FEL` and `SER` but your picture has Divisions `KEP` and `SER` - what is the official start time of `KEP` (or is there some default for any department that is not `FEL` or `SER`?)

Comment: No apparent attempt to answer the question themselves. No code to work with.

Comment: Also, how to deal with times that are under an hour or where `X.Y` hours were worked? Treat them as is, round to the nearest quarter hour (round up, round down, banker's round, something else)?

Comment: I'm assuming this is an assignment and you'v

Comment: It was a typo error. Corrected as KEP. As for hour, if it's less than .5, then round down ie 7.4 will be treated as 7.0 hours. If it's above .5, then round up ie 7.6 will be treated as 8.0 hours. However, if it is 7.5 hours, it will be treated as 7.5 hours.

Comment: When someone starts at `SER` on Saturday evening at 9 PM and works for 5 hours, does their one hour of overtime count as Saturday overtime (`OT15`) or Sunday (`OT20`)?

Comment: It will be treated are Saturday overtime (OT15).

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into parts, and iterate:

```
-- To start with, we need to know how long someone actually worked
-- for each period, so let's calculate that:
;WITH EmployeeTimecardData AS
    (
    SELECT TS.[Date] AS [Period],
        TS.Employee AS [EmployeeID],
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TS.TimeIn, TS.TimeOut)) as [Time Worked],
        MAX(TS.[Day]) AS [DW]
    FROM Timesheet TS
    GROUP BY TS.[Date], TS.Employee
    ),
-- Then, there is some rounding that needs to be done,
-- (there is probably a better way to do this, but you get the idea)
EmployeeTimecards AS
    (
    SELECT ETD.[Perid],
        ETD.EmployeeID,
        CASE
        WHEN ROUND(ETD.[Time Worked], 1) % 10 > 0.5
            THEN CEILING(ETD.[Time Worked])
        WHEN ROUND(ETD.[Time Worked], 1) % 10 < 0.5
            THEN FLOOR(ETD.[Time Worked])
        ELSE
            ROUND(ETD.[Time Worked], 1)
        END AS [Time Worked],
        ETD.DW
    FROM EmployeeTimecardData AS [ETD]
    )
-- Now that we have the data in the shape we want it,
-- we can start our calculations
SELECT [ET].Period,
    [ET].EmloyeeID,
    CASE
    WHEN NHL.[Date] IS NOT NULL OR ET.DW = 'SUN'
        THEN 0
    WHEN ET.DW = 'SAT'
        THEN
            CASE
            WHEN ET.[Time Worked] > 4
                THEN 4
            ELSE
                ET.[Time Worked]
            END
    ELSE
        CASE
        WHEN ET.[Time Worked] > 8
            THEN 8
        ELSE
            ET.[Time Worked]
        END
    END AS [Normal],
-- OT15 and OT20 are left as an exercise for the reader :-)
FROM EmployeeTimecards AS [ET]
LEFT OUTER JOIN NationalHoliday [NHL]
    ON [ET].[Period] = [NHL].[Date]
```

Comment: the above does not take into the account of official start time for the respective divisions ie 7.30 for KEP and 8.00 for SER. Possible to include that ?

Comment: @Bob - there is no way to tell, with the given schema what shift an employee came in for, so no (for example, is an employee who comes in at 2 PM coming in 5.5 hours *early* for the evening shift or 6.5 hours *late* for the morning shift?)

Comment: I hv executed it & there are some issues especially those start from late PM to the next day AM. For eg, started on 20131231 18:38 and completed on 20140101 6:30. System computed as -932

Comment: Ok, I managed to resolve it & it's working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, there are still some small issues, especially for those  start from late PM to the next day AM. For eg, started on 20131229 18:53 and completed on 20131230 4.23. System computed as 16 hours !!